# How to unzip from rx.Observable

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, gzip, unzip

I'm downloading a gzipped file, and reading the unzipped content line by line. 
My code looks like this:

```
        ChannelSftp channel = getJSchChannel();
        try (InputStream is = channel.get(fileName);
             GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis)))
        {
            reader.readLine(); 
            ...
        }
```

Since the unzipping and the rest of the block are cpu intensive, I would like to make it run in parallel to downloading file (it's a huge file). 
I thought of using rx.Observable to handle all data flow, but I encounter a problem with unzipping.
Suppose I wrap the file input stream with observable:

```
Observable<byte[]> obs = StringObservable.from(channel.get(fileName));
```

How do I proceed from here? Is there a way to unzip content of an observable?

Comment: Cannot you just put your unzip code inside a `.map` operator?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an unzipping code. I use the GZIPInputStream above, that works over InputStream only, of course...

Comment: And what's the issue with that? You can use an InputStream inside an operator. You could create the observable with `Observable.fromCallable`, and put that code from above inside the lambda.

Comment: The Observable wrapping the file InputStream emits byte array. I want the next observable to unzip, but I can't transform from bytes observable to InputStream and wrap it with the GZIPInputStream. I don't want the first observable to emits already-unzipped data, since I want to separate file reading from unzipping, thread wise. I hope I made myself clear this time.